# How to set keys to a relationship table in Oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Please before judging bear in mind that I don't understand that's why I ask the question. I am discouraged by some down voting that has occured in the past.

I have to create a database in Oracle 10g and I am using the template to create a new table.
The database is about an imaginary facebook application.

Amongst others it includes relationship "like" with 3 attributes all of which are supposed to be keys:

```
like:

username: key
message_author: key
message_code: key
```

as I said like is a relationship between two entities user and message.

I tried to setup the table like as 3 foreign keys connected to the other tables but oracle will not accept it.

I get the following error message:

> Failed Creating FK like_FK2 ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
>
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception

I suppose I am doing something wrong with the keys, but I can't understand what it is

SQL commands:

```
CREATE table "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" (
    "ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ"    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    "ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    "ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ"   NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ")
    REFERENCES "ΧΡΗΣΤΗΣ" ("ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ")

/
ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK2" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ")
    REFERENCES "ΜΗΝΥΜΑ" ("ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ")

/
ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK3" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")
    REFERENCES "ΜΗΝΥΜΑ" ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")

/
alter table "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" add
    constraint ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_UK1
    unique ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")
/
```

Comment: Can you post your DDL statements?

Comment: ΑΡΕΣΕΙ = like TABLE NAME

ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ = username
ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ = message_author
ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ = message_code

Comment: you are adding FKS to tables that you did not show the DDL for.  Please show ALL the relevant create statements for all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Before you specify any relationship constraints and other constraints like `UNIQUE`, make sure that the tables exist before you code and run these statements. I am editing your code a little bit in my answer:

```
CREATE table "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" (
    "ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ"    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    "ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    "ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ"   NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL -- PRECISION AND SCALE MUST BE MENTIONED FOR NUMBER DATA TYPE
)
/

CREATE table "ΜΗΝΥΜΑ" (
     "ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ"  VARCHAR2(30) -- data types are recommended to be the same
     "ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ"    NUMBER(10,2)
     -- Other columns go here
)
/

CREATE TABLE "ΧΡΗΣΤΗΣ" (
     "ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ"     VARCHAR(30)
     -- Other columns go here
)
/

-- After you create all the tables, you can code the alter table statements
-- that would add all your necessary constraints.

ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ")
    REFERENCES "ΧΡΗΣΤΗΣ" ("ΟΝΟΜΑΧΡΗΣΤΗ")
/

ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK2" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ")
    REFERENCES "ΜΗΝΥΜΑ" ("ΣΥΓΦΕΑΣ_ΜΗΝΤΟΣ")
/

ALTER TABLE "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" ADD CONSTRAINT "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_FK3" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")
    REFERENCES "ΜΗΝΥΜΑ" ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")
/

alter table "ΑΡΕΣΕΙ" add
    constraint ΑΡΕΣΕΙ_UK1
    unique ("ΚΩΔΜΗΝΥΜΑΤΟΣ")
/
```

Also, keep in mind that there is a constraint called `PRIMARY KEY` which allows you to put unique and not null constraints on a column at the same time. I recommend you read the documentation provided by Oracle at docs.oracle.com for your reference.

Also, I hope you mention all your table names and column names in ASCII (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) characters. Unicode characters as object identifiers may be supported but are difficult to maintain.